# How to setup myget build to use my .nuspec file

Tags: nuget, myget

in my source I have specified *.nuspec file with filed full metadata. When I build this source on myGet I receive .nupkg with different metadata (Author: Wonka, Description: Description).

In Package details on myget.org metadata are good :/

How to setup myGet build to use my .nuspec filemetadata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file was in the wrong folder.

Thanks @maartenba!

Comment: Hi. I have the same problem. What is the correct location for .nuspect file?

Comment: In project with the same name. [example](https://github.com/marska/habitrpg-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/src/HabitRPG.Client/HabitRPG.Client.nuspec)

Answer (score 2):

What is the structure of your application? E.g.:

- What is the project name? (of the .csproj file)
- What is the NuSpec name? (of the .nuspec file)
- Where are both located? Under the same folder?